How to display dates in Angular based on client's timezone stored in the database?
I am working on an application that has multiple clients from different regions, including France. In my case, some of the clients are from French Guiana, which has a different timezone (GMT -3) compared to mainland France. I store the timezone for each client in the database.
The challenge I'm facing is how to properly display dates in the client-side (Angular) based on the client's timezone, regardless of the user's local timezone. For example, if I am in Japan, I want the dates to be displayed according to the client's timezone (e.g., GMT -3 for a client in French Guiana).
Here are the steps I am following:
I retrieve the client’s timezone from the backend (stored in the database).
I want to ensure that dates are displayed correctly in the Angular front-end using the client’s timezone, not the local timezone.
What is the best approach to achieve this in Angular? Should I use any specific library like moment-timezone or Intl.DateTimeFormat?
